# jQuery Load localstorage before Page Load

Tags: local-storage, themes

Is there a way to load localstorage before page load ?

I'm using localstorage for ( DARK MODE ) on my website.

```
//Dark Mode & store in local storage
jQuery('#button-dl').on('click', function() {
    if (jQuery('body').hasClass('light')) {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
        localStorage.theme = 'dark';
    }
    else {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('dark').addClass('light');
        localStorage.theme = 'light';
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "before everything"? If you mean when the page loads, jQuery's document.ready would be where I'd do it.

Comment: Yes I mean before page load, thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Ok - then use document.ready :)

Comment: Ok I understand why is loading first default CSS, it's because Im using a caching plugin.